# How to find the upper and lower bounds of $a(n)=\frac{n+1}{2^n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Determine if the following sequence is bounded or unbounded.

$$a(n)=\frac{n+1}{2^n}.$$

I can check whether the function is bounded or unbounded via definition which this function is bounded due to
$\lvert f(x)\rvert\leq M$ however I don't know how to check the upper bound of the function.

Comment: Have you tried writing down the values of $a(n)$ for the first few $n$?

Comment: Your post could use some improvements. First, please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the mathematics, in both your title and the text. Second, your *complete question* should appear in the text itself; don't put your question in the title only. Finally, you say that you "can check whether the function is bounded...", but you should also give the *mathematical details* of what you did in carrying out that check.

Comment: Note that the function is decreasing

Comment: Use $1+x\leq e^x$.

Comment: Show that $0<a(n+1)< a(n)$ for all $n>1$

Answer (score 0):

When $n$ is negative the $2^n$ goes into the numerator so it isn't bounded from below in the interval $(-\infty, 0]$ hence isn't bounded. However, it could be proven that it is bounded from above by taking the derivative of $a(n)$, which is $\frac{1-\ln 2(n+1)}{2^n}$ and then setting this equal to $0$. The solution is $\frac{1+\ln 2}{\ln 2}$ so $a(n)$ is bounded from above.

Comment: Is there a way to show that it is bounded via |f(x)|<= M because the assignment doesn't allow me to use calculus?